# deploying felix webconsole in spring mvc over felix http bridge

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi, apache-felix, web-console

I've Spring MVC webapplication which starts osgi container using ServletContextListener (osgi http bridge). I am trying to deploy felix webconsole along with other bundles, bundle gets started, but I am not able to access it.
In my web.xml
Spring DispatherServlet is configured for URL '/'
Felix ProxyServlet is configured for URL '/ext/*'

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>extension</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ext/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried to access webconsole using "http://localhost:8080/my-app/ext/system/console" (results 503) and "http://localhost:8080/my-app/system/console" (results 404) with no luck.

Upon debugging I see that for 'ext/system/console' URL, org.apache.felix.http.proxy.DispatcherTracker.DispatcherTracker#getDispatcher() method call in ProxyServlet#service() method returns NULL.

Can anybody point me, what I am missing here ?